# Using custom Task in CC.net configuration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have created the following custom task for Cruise Control .net, but I can't find a single reference of how you add a custom task to the project configuration. Does anyone have a helpful example of how to add a reference to a custom task in cc.net?

(below is my new task)

```
public class RestoreDb : TaskBase
{
    #region Parameters

    [Required]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DbName { get; set; }

    public string BackupFileName { get; set; }

    #endregion

    protected override bool Execute(ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IIntegrationResult result)
    {
        bool returnResult = false;
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = ServerName;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
            connection.Open();

            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

            if (server.Databases[DbName] != null)
            {
                Log.Info("Dropping existing " + DbName + " on " + ServerName);
                server.Databases[DbName].Drop();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(DbName + " on " + ServerName + " doesn't exist.");
            }

            Log.Info("Restoring " + DbName + " on " + ServerName);
            Database newDb = new Database(server, DbName);

            Restore rs = new Restore();
            rs.NoRecovery = false;

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(server.Settings.BackupDirectory + "\\" + BackupFileName);
            rs.Devices.AddDevice(fi.FullName, DeviceType.File);
            rs.Database = DbName;
            rs.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            rs.ReplaceDatabase = true;

            DataTable fileContents = rs.ReadFileList(server);
            string originalDbName = fileContents.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            string originalLogFileName = fileContents.Rows[1][0].ToString();
            rs.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(originalDbName, 
            string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\{0}.mdf", DbName)));

            rs.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(originalLogFileName,
            string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\{0}_1.ldf", DbName)));

            rs.SqlRestore(server);
            Log.Info("Restoring done.");
            returnResult = true; // success!
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
            returnResult = false;
        }
        return returnResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically tossed this because there are no examples anywhere of how to add a custom task to the cc.net config. below is the powershell script I wrote, that does the exact same steps.

```
$ServerName = 'servernamehere';
$DatabaseName = 'newDbNameHere';
$BackupFile = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\backupFileHere.bak';
if($args[0])
{
    $ServerName = $args[0];
}
if($args[1])
{
    $DatabaseName = $args[1];
}
if($args[2])
{
    $BackupFile = $args[2];
}

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended")
try 
{
    $Server = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $ServerName

    If ($Server.Databases.Contains($DatabaseName))
    {
        write-host "Dropping existing " $DatabaseName " on " $ServerName;
        #$Server.Databases[$DatabaseName].SetOffline();
        $Server.Databases[$DatabaseName].Drop();
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $DatabaseName " on " $ServerName " doesn't exist.";
    }
    $Database = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database") ($Server, $DatabaseName);

    $restore = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore');
    $restore.NoRecovery = $false;

    $fil=new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem";
    $fil.DeviceType='File';
    $fil.Name= $BackupFile;
    $restore.Action="Database";
    $restore.Devices.Add($fil);
    $restore.Database=$DatabaseName;
    $restore.ReplaceDatabase = $true;

    #retrieving the backup file's original database values so we can replace them
    $FileContents = $restore.ReadFileList($Server);
    $originalDbName =  $FileContents.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    $originalLogFileName = $FileContents.Rows[1][0].ToString();

    #replacing the bak files original file names with the new file names
    $mdf = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" ($originalDbName,
        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$DatabaseName.mdf");
    $restore.RelocateFiles.Add($mdf);
    $ldf = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" ($originalLogFileName,
        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$DatabaseName_Log.mdf");
    $restore.RelocateFiles.Add($ldf);


    write-host "Restoring database $DatabaseName  on  $ServerName from file $BackupFile";

        $restore.SqlRestore($Server);
        write-host "Restore Complete";
}
catch [System.Exception] {
  # $_ is set to the ErrorRecord of the exception
  $currentException = $_.Exception;
  write-host "Root Exception: " $currentException.Message;
  While($currentException.InnerException)
  {
    $currentException = $_.Exception.InnerException;
    write-host "Inner Exception: " $currentException.Message;
  }
  write-host "Restore Failed.";
  exit 0; #failure
}    
exit 1;
```

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the question you posted

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the version you're using, so I'm answering this with the assumption that users will be using newer versions.  I have built this based upon experience in developing custom tasks for [cruisecontrol.net](/questions/tagged/cruisecontrol.net) 1.8.3.0

You can find some of the [api](/questions/tagged/api) [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) for creating and consuming [plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins) here:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/DevInfo_MakingPlugins

**EDIT:** I'd like to note that the CruiseControl.NET documentation at the link provided has been updated and now contains much of the info contained here.

This documentation is fairly light weight however, and doesn't really cover the range of topics you'll end up having questions about when you attempt to create your own task.

The process, as simply as I can put it;

- Your project for custom tasks needs to reference the following assemblies, which can be found in the root CruiseControl.NET server folder.

  - NetReflector.dll
  - ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Dll
  - Any other Assembly you reference which is not part of the .NET 3.5 Framework
- When constructing a custom task you will need to mark any Class or Property you wish to expose with a Reflector Attribute to make them available in ccnet.config
- In order for CruiseControl.NET to consume your custom library you are required to name the assembly with this convention:  ccnet.WhateverYouWantHere.plugin.dll
- You will need to place this assembly in your CruiseControl.NET Server folder.

  - If you have setup a plugins directory by supplying a value for PluginLocation  in your ccnet.exe.config, you will need to place your assembly there instead.
  - Any assembly you reference in your project that isn't already in the CruiseControl.NET server folder will need to added to the server or plugins folder as well

```cs
namespace MyTasks
{
    [ReflectorType("MyCustomTask")]
    public class MyCustomTaskClass : ITask 
    {
        [ReflectorProperty("MyCustomTaskProperty")]
        public string CustomProperty { get; set; }

        public string MyInternalPublicProperty { get; set; }

        public void Run(IIntegrationResult result){}
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The name of the property and the name you expose to the ccnet.config do not have to match.

In order to reference created tasks, labellers, etc. you simply need to use the string supplied in the Reflector attributes.

```xml
<project>
    <tasks>
        <MyCustomTask MyCustomTaskProperty="This is an example"/>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

If you attempted to use this code, and also add a reference to MyInternalPublicProperty in your tag it will not work:

```xml
<project>
    <tasks>
        <MyCustomTask MyInternalPublicProperty="This is will throw an exception in the service and not reload the ccnet config until the invalid content is removed from the config"/>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

This is because you didn't decorate the property with it's own [ReflectorProperty()] attribute.